Using Spring WebClient to exchange messages on microservices preventing boilerplate codes
Spring now says Spring Cloud OpenFeign is feature-complete, and won't be developed anymore. And they promote using WebClient instead of OpenFeign.
OpenFeign proxies can resolve other service from discovery service behind the scene, but creating a proxy for each interface with WebClient makes us have lots of boilerplate code.
Isn't there anyway to avoid all those boilerplate codes, and create proxies backed by WebClient on the fly?

We don't promote webclient as a replacement for feign, but http interface clients https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/integration/rest-clients.html#rest-http-interface

Feign automatically discovers webservice endpoint through discovery service, how to do that with WebClient?

Currently you would use an@Loadbalanced annotated rest template or web client to build the interface client. The auto configuration will come later this year
